# Defining a symbol for Conditional attribute in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, conditional-statements

**[EDIT]**
For someone who came across this page for some reason,
things have changed now. Starting Unity 2017, you have to define the same symbol in both files(Callee and Caller) regardless of the file location.
Below was the issue before Unity 2017.
I'll leave this for the record.

---

In standard C#, if I want to call a method with a conditional attribute, I have to define a symbol for it in the file where the method is **CALLED**. But in Unity, it seems different. It only works when I put the line in the file where the method **EXISTS**. Let's say, there are two script files in a Unity project like this.

**ClassForMySymbol.cs**

```
class ClassForMySymbol {
    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("MY_SYMBOL")]
    public static void Print() {
        Debug.Log ("This method is called.");
    }
}
```

**Test.cs**

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        ClassForMySymbol.Print();
    }
}
```

This will only work when I define "MY_SYMBOL" in **ClassForMySymbol.cs** but not **Test.cs**.

I don't get what's happening. Is this normal? What am I missing here?

PS. This question is not about #define's scope or defining a global symbol.

Comment: Did not look into it but it's probably mono vs .net, 2.0 vs current thing (if not a tech. mistake from your side but based on the above, it's not)

Comment: @Mark hmm.. It may have something to do with Mono 2.x as you said.

Comment: @zwcloud Putting the symbol in Test.cs doesn't help at all unless I put it in ClassForMySymbol.cs. It's exactly opposite in .NET C#.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It is exactly the opposite behaviour in Unity3D compared to .NET. I have tested on VS2015 and Unity3D 5.3.0.

Comment: @zwcloud Thanks for the test! Now I can say it's not my mistake at least :) BTW I also tested on VS2008 too!

Comment: @Jenix Not just mono but the fact it's old. It's very likely this is a change in behaviour old vs new .NET (btw Unity is planning to upgrade .NET version but it's painful, especially for il2cpp so... don't expect this happen tomorrow)

Comment: @zwcloud After some trying, it turned out it's Unity not Mono. Monodevelop editor shows just like Visual Studio. If I don't follow .NET syntax it just greys out the code, but the actual result will be different. However when I put in different folders for different script compilation order, say Test.cs file in the Assets folder and ClassForMySymbol.cs in the Plugins folder, then it worked just as expected! Still don't know why but at least can tell when this will happen.